# Convergence for a non-linear second order difference equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

In my work, I need to study the convergence of sequence defined by the non-linear recurrence relation
$$
u_0,u_1>0, \qquad \forall n\in \mathbb N, \; u_{n+2}=a\ln(1+u_n)+b\ln(1+u_{n+1})
$$
with fixed $a,b> 0$.

For $a=b=1$ Wolfram gives the limit $-1-2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}}\right)$. (W is the Lambert function) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. I'm looking for ideas to study convergence of this sequence. I would suspect that non-classical arguments are needed to do so.

Note: I have already asked the question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3720998/793015), but it was closed quickly for a reason that I do not understand.

Comment: Something seems to be odd about the claimed limit: the corresponding fixed point equation is $u = (a+b)\ln(1+u)$. If $a+b \le 1$, this equation has no solution in $[0,\infty)$ except for $0$; for $a+b > 1$ it has precisely one more solution in $[0,\infty)$ (besides $0$), but this solution does certainly depend on $a+b$.

Comment: I forgot to say that wolfram gives this limit in the case a = b = 1

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I made an edit to the question to tidy it up a bit. I also changed the title to make it a bit more informative. (The wording "Needing proof for..." in the title of a question is not really helpful to readers who browse a list of questions.)

Comment: That said, I am not sure why the question was downvoted. I might be overlooking something, but at first glance the question whether the sequence always converges does not seem obvious to me. (By the way, one more remark to the OP: I would suggest that you also add an explanation of the notation $W_{-1}$ to the question.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you for supporting
 the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I would suspect that non-classical arguments are needed to do so.*

All you need to know is that $t\mapsto \frac 1{1+t}$ is a decreasing function, so for $0<x\le x'$ we have $\frac{\log(1+x')}{\log(1+x)}\le \frac {x'}x$. This immediately implies that the mapping $T:(x,y)\mapsto (y,a\log(1+x)+b\log(1+y))$ is non-expanding in the metric $d((x,y),(x',y'))=max(|\log x-\log x'|,|\log y-\log y'|)$ on $(0,+\infty)^2$ and $T^2$ is a weak contraction ($d(T^2p,T^2q)<d(p,q)$ if $p\ne q$).

The next step is to consider the equation $x=(a+b)\log(1+x)$ and notice that either $a+b\le 1$ (in which case the iterations trivially converge to $(0,0)$, i.e., "escape to infinity" in our metric) or $a+b>1$ in which case there is a positive solution $x_0$ of that equation and $T$ maps every compact ball $B(p_0,r)$ into itself where $p_0=(x_0,x_0)$ is a fixed point of $T$. If $(u_0,u_1)$ lies in that ball, we can apply the usual result about weak contractions on compact sets to conclude that we have convergence to $p_0$.

*but it was closed quickly for a reason that I do not understand.*

The closure reason cited on MSE is totally ridiculous IMHO. The very fact that you ask a well-posed mathematical question is a sufficient proof of "relevance to you" and nobody is obliged to verify the "relevance to the community" (whatever it might mean) when asking. The only possible reason for closure I see is that the question is rather trivial, but, given the usual amount of total junk floating on MSE, I doubt that it was what determined its fate. So, please, accept my apologies for the MSE users behavior, ignore this incident and keep asking :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. I see more clearly how to attack these kinds of questions. thank you for your support

Comment: @fedja it clearly says the question was closed for not providing context. You can't just ask a mathematical question with nothing else (e.g. context, attempts,...) on MSE

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x,y) = \ln(1+x) + \ln(1+y)$, and $p = -1 - 2 W_{-1}(-1/(2 \sqrt{e}))$, it is easy to verify that $f(p,p) = p$.  Moreover, it appears numerically that $\|(x_3,x_4) - (p,p)\| < \|(x_1, x_2) - (p,p)\|$ where $x_3 = f(x_1, x_2)$ and $x_4 = f(x_2, x_3)$
and $(x_1, x_2)$ is sufficiently close to $(p,p)$.
Here is a plot of $\|(x_3,x_4) - (p,p)\|^2/\|(x_1,x_2) - (p,p)\|^2$ as a function of $(x_1,x_2)$ for $0.1 \le x_1 \le 5$, $0.1 \le x_2 \le 5$.

[image]

If $(x_1,x_2)$ is in some circle centred at $(p,p)$ which is contained in the region where $\|(x_3,x_4) - (p,p)\| < \| (x_1, x_2) - (p,p)\|$,
we will have $x_n \to p$ as $n \to \infty$.