# Integrability of a function under a condition on its Fourier transform

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that its Fourier transform $\hat f$ equals zero in a neighborhood of zero.

Let $F$ be function such that $\hat F$ exists and

$$\hat f(x) =x\hat F(x),\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Prove that $F\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Any hints on how to prove that?

I already asked [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3646361/prove-that-f-in-l1-mathbbr?noredirect=1#comment7493238_3646361), I hope it will have a chance here

Comment: Could you say more about where this question/problem arose, and why it is supposed to have a positive answer? That is: does this come from a paper you are reading? A course you are taking? etc

Comment: it is a question of a professor without indications. If F is a primitive of f (F '= f) we see that $ \hat f (x) = i x \hat F (x), \forall x \in \mathbb {R} $

Comment: What precisely does "such that $\hat F$ exists" mean?

Comment: As for your [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363180/102946) I changed the title to make it a bit more informative, and I changed the format of the link. May I kindly suggest for future questions that you try to (i) choose titles that contain a bit more concrete information about the question (phrases such as "Prove that" don't really add much information to the title) and (ii) use urls within links instead of writing down the entire url in plain text?

Comment: @Jochen Glueck thanks for the formatting (title and link)
For your question, I am a little embarrassed because the question does not specify the meaning. I believe in the sence of moderate distributions. If the problem is badly posed I will wait seven september to see the professor.

Comment: The assumption about $\widehat{F}$ existing is unnecessary. We could define $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\, dt \in C_0$ and take its distributional FT. In fact, it's also immediately (from $\widehat{f}=x\widehat{F}$) that $F\in L^2$, so we don't really need distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\widehat{f}=0$ near zero, so we can write $\widehat{F}=\widehat{g}\widehat{f}$ with a function $\widehat{g}\in C^{\infty}$, $\widehat{g}(x)=1/x$ for $|x|\ge a>0$.

Since $\widehat{g}'' = -(t^2 g)\,\widehat{}\in L^1$, we have $|g(t)|\lesssim 1/t^2$. Moreover, $g\in L^2\subseteq L^1_{\textrm{loc}}$. So $g\in L^1$, and thus also $F=g*f\in L^1$, since $f\in L^1$ by assumption.

Comment: We wrote the same proof!

Comment: @ Christian Remling 
 Thank you very very very much

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\hat f$ vanishes in $[-2a,2a]$ and take $\phi$ odd, vanishing in $[-a,a]$ and equal to $1/x$ if $|x| \ge 2a$. Then  $\hat F=\phi \hat f$ and $F=\psi*f$ where $\psi$ is the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi$
$$\psi (\xi)=2 \int_a^\infty \phi(x)\sin (\xi x)\, dx.$$ Then $\psi$ is bounded for $|\xi| \le 1$ and, integrating by parts twice, decays at least as $1/\xi^2$ at infinity. This shows that $\psi \in L^1$ and $F \in L^1$, too.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune Thank's so much

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune  According to my teacher, we can only express a fourier transform or its inverse by an integral if the function is in L ^ 1, here the function is in L ^ 2, the inversion formula $\psi (\xi)=\int_0^\infty \phi(x)e^{(i\xi x)}\, dx.=2 \int_a^\infty \phi(x)\sin (\xi x)\, dx.$ is not justified

Comment: If $\phi_R(x)=\phi \chi_{(0,R)}$, then $\phi_R \to \phi$ and $\hat{\phi_R} \to \hat{\phi}$ in $L^2$. But $\hat{\phi_R}=\int_0^R \phi (x) \sin(\xi x)dx \to \psi$ pointwise.

Comment: thank's so much